# What is the "Super Stimpak Debuff" in New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

The in-game information for the Super Stimpak in *Fallout: New Vegas* lists two effects: "Super Stimpak Debuff" and "HP +24(3s)." What does the "Super Stimpak Debuff" part mean? There's not much info on the Internet about this yet, but my search came up with two theories:

- Even though Super Stimpaks do a great job of healing — and 24 HP/sec for three seconds is pretty good, no question — they actually end up damaging the player after a while
- Any status effects that are active get wiped away when a Super Stimpak is applied

Which of these two is right? Or is the right answer some other thing entirely? In the unlikely event that it matters: I'm playing the 360 version.

Comment: I assume this is on hardcore because it's healing over time instead of instantaneously? Do regular stim-paks have a "Stimpak debuff"?

Comment: @Raven, yes, sorry, Hardcore. Regular stimpaks have no debuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It refers to "Stimpak Sickness" a short duration -1 Str, -1 Agi effect applied by Super Stimpacks.

Answer (score 0):

The Debuff is on the regular difficulty setting, as that is what I'm playing on now.
The base stat's for the Super Stimpak are as follows:
+75 HP(Immediate)
-3 HP (After 1 minute)
-6 HP (After 2 minutes)

Source for this information is at the following link.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Super_stimpak

Comment: stats above are for the Super Stimpak in Fallout and Fallout 2.